# WMQ SSL High Availability JMS connection using 7.1 jars getting error

Tags: ssl, jms, ibm-mq

I am getting below error while connecting to SSL enabled queue in Websphere MQ using 7.1 jars through JMS.

Code :

```
public MQMessageSender(String channelName, String hostName,
                   String portNumber, String queueManagerName, String queueName) {
    // Create a MQQueue Factory Object
    try {
        mqConnectionFact = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        mqConnectionFact.setChannel("xxx.SVRCONN");
        mqConnectionFact.setPort(Integer.parseInt("xxxx"));
        mqConnectionFact.setHostName("host1");
        //mqConnectionFact.setConnectionNameList("host2(port2)");           
        mqConnectionFact.setClientReconnectOptions(JMSC.MQCNO_RECONNECT_Q_MGR);
        mqConnectionFact.setQueueManager("XXXXX");
        mqConnectionFact.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);
        mqConnectionFact.setSSLCipherSuite("SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA");
        qConnection = mqConnectionFact.createQueueConnection();

        qConnection.start();
        qSession = qConnection.createQueueSession(false,
                              Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        requestQueue = qSession.createQueue(queueName);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Error :

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with
compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2399' ('MQRC_SSL_PEER_NAME_ERROR').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:209)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2399;
AMQ9204: Connection to host 'host1' rejected.
[1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2399;
AMQ9640: SSL invalid peer name, channel '?', attribute 'OID.2.5.4.17 (x2)'.
[5=OID.2.5.4.17 (x2)]],3=host1(port1),5=RemotePeerName.setValue]
```

Answer (score 1):

`reason '2399' ('MQRC_SSL_PEER_NAME_ERROR')` is reporting that is the error. See [2399 (095F) (RC2399): MQRC_SSL_PEER_NAME_ERROR](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q044270_.htm). Additionally, you have the following error message:

```
AMQ9640: SSL invalid peer name, channel '?', attribute 'OID.2.5.4.17 (x2)'.
[5=OID.2.5.4.17 (x2)]],3=host1(port1),5=RemotePeerName.setValue]
```

which is telling you which part of the peerName was not recognised. It says, `OID.2.5.4.17` which is Postal Code.

A brief Internet search reveals an APAR for this very problem, [IC83494: WMQ V7.1: JMS CLIENT CONNECTION VIA SSL ENABLED CHANNEL FAILS WITH RC 2399 MQRC_SSL_PEER_NAME_ERROR.](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC83494)

This APAR is included in V7.1 FixPac 3.

Comment: Thank you @Morgan Hughson, I replicated this issue (CC=2;RC=2399;AMQ9204) with MQ client libs ver: "7.5.0.1 - p750-001-130308", when I switched to "7.5.0.2 - p750-002-131001_DE" it started to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good pieces of advice and pointers link to from this article.https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/websphere_mq_v7_java_and_jms_ssl_problems_and_solutions?lang=en

You've got reconnect enabled, was the problem on the first connect or when reconnecting?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Calanais. It's problem on the first connect itself. I am not able to get the connection